# How to handle dropped frames when using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVAssetWriter to write high FPS buffer frames?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm creating an app to record high FPS videos (120/240 FPS). I notice that every time I record a video, a lot of frames is dropped constantly.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        var mode: CMAttachmentMode = 0
        let reason = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, key: kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_DroppedFrameReason, attachmentModeOut: &mode)
        print("did drop sample buffer, reason: \(String(describing: reason))")
    }
```

> did drop sample buffer, reason: Optional('usually it could be OutOfBuffers, Discontinuity, or FrameWasLate')

This is how I set up the capture session and etc:

```
private func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        // This is set to reduce memory consumption, bigger resolution means more memory consumption
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
        
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back).devices
        
        guard let videoCaptureDevice = devices.first,
              let audioCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio) else {
            return
        }
        
        captureDevice = videoCaptureDevice
        
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
        let audioInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
        
        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
            audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }
        
        if captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput),
           captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
            captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
        } else {
            return
        }
        
        videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        setupDataOutput()
        
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.previewLayer.frame = self.previewLayerView.bounds
            self.previewLayerView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        }
        
        previewLayerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        for vFormat in videoCaptureDevice.formats {
            let ranges = vFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges as [AVFrameRateRange]
            let frameRate = ranges.first!
            
            if frameRate.maxFrameRate == 240 {
                do {
                    try videoCaptureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
                    videoCaptureDevice.activeFormat = vFormat
                    videoCaptureDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: Int32(120))
                    videoCaptureDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: Int32(120))
                    videoCaptureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print("Could not lock for configuration")
                }
            }
        }
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    }

private func setupDataOutput() {
        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [
            String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
        ]
        
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                self.captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            }
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureQueue)
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = false
        }
    }
```

And this is how I set the AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWritingInput [(based on this article)](https://medium.com/@krzechowski/avassetwriter-for-high-fps-camera-stream-90c33861b7ee):

```
private func setupWriterInput(metadata: AssetWritingMetadata,
                                  vFormatDescription: CMFormatDescription? = nil,
                                  recommendedVideoSettings: [String: Any]? = nil) throws {
        
        // You have to initialize a new `AVAssetWriter` everytime you want to record a new video.
        assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(url: metadata.targetURL, fileType: .mov)
        assetWriter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false
        
        var recommendedVideoSettings = recommendedVideoSettings
        if recommendedVideoSettings == nil {
            let bitsPerPixel: CGFloat
            if metadata.resolutionWidth * metadata.resolutionHeight < 640 * 480 {
                bitsPerPixel = 4.05 // Relative to AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium/Low
            } else {
                bitsPerPixel = 10.1 // Relative to AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
            }
            
            let compressionProperties: NSDictionary = [
                AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: CGFloat(metadata.resolutionWidth) * CGFloat(metadata.resolutionHeight) * bitsPerPixel,
                AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: Double(metadata.fps.rawValue)!,
                AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey: Double(metadata.fps.rawValue)!
            ]
            
            let videoSettings: [String: Any] = [
                AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                AVVideoWidthKey: metadata.resolutionWidth,
                AVVideoHeightKey: metadata.resolutionHeight,
                AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: compressionProperties
            ]
            
            recommendedVideoSettings = videoSettings
        }
        
        if assetWriter.canApply(outputSettings: recommendedVideoSettings, forMediaType: .video) {
            assetVideoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: recommendedVideoSettings, sourceFormatHint: vFormatDescription)
            assetVideoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
            assetVideoWriterInput.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
            
            if assetWriter.canAdd(assetVideoWriterInput) {
                assetWriter.add(assetVideoWriterInput)
            } else {
                throw "Asset Writer couldn't add the input"
            }
        } else {
            throw "Asset Writer couldn't apply the output settings"
        }
    }
```

My question is how to prevent the capture data output to drop frames while recording and writing video frames? I've actually done some research and found this [great article](https://medium.com/@krzechowski/avassetwriter-for-high-fps-camera-stream-90c33861b7ee) mentioning that if the processing time of each frame is more that 1/FPS, then we should copy the sample buffer and store it to process later like this:

```
private var toProcess:[CVPixelBuffer] = [];

if let pixelBuffer:CVImageBuffer =    
   CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
    let copy = pixelBuffer.copy();              
    self.toProcess.append(copy);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this. May I ask which part I should copy the frames and process them later? I'm hoping that maybe I could have an example code and an explanation so I could understand this better because I'm still very new to this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's important what kind of `queue` you use to receive video frames. In my observations `serial` queue works best. From yours code sample it's not obvious what kind of queue you use, so basically ensure that you are using serial queue.